# Which Git.EXE should I point Visual Studio Code toward?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, settings

I have installed GIT multiple times in both hard drives, although VS Code is detecting none of them. On trying to fix it, I run into the problem that I can't just seem to find the naked, basic Git.EXE. What does the program expect?

[A picture of the Everything app listing multiple Git exes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcNaJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have to options:

- You should choose to add Git to the `PATH` when you install it (better option).
  You could update the PATH by adding the path `[git install folder]\usr\bin`
- In the VSCode settings, add the path toward the `git.exe` file (The path is empty in your image)